# Adobe Premiere Exports only video

Tags: video, premiere, export

I combined video and audio from different sources. I intentionally slowed the audio down, but when I export it, I get only video.

Also, the audio I'm using is a mono. I tried to save it with both mono and stereo settings in the export and both didn't work.
[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! We'll need a lot more information to help you. What are your project settings? What were your output settings? You said you get only video but then you say the audio is slowed down. Which problem is it? Video with no audio or a video with audio that is slowed down from the original? What player are you using that you have the problem?

Comment: The audio that I added to the video inside the project was slowed down (intentionally), and after the export did not work in all the players I tried (BSplayer, Media Player, VLC)
I exported it in format H.264 with a Match Source preset. 
The project settings are default, I guess. I am really new to this, so I did not change anything.

Comment: Can you post screen shots of the export settings window?

Comment: Hi, I added it in an answer